# How to restart VDI Windows 10 pro

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vdi

Sorry for the stupid question. I mechanically turned off a VDI that I work on daily. Since then, I can no longer connect to this VDI.

Normally, I use the remote access desktop icon, a popup opens and I type my password to access the VDI.

But when I click on it, I have a popup with the following message:

> Remote computer is turned off
>
> Ensure the remote computer is turned on, connected to the network, and
> remote access is enabled

When I right-click on the remote access desktop icon, I access this content by opening it with the notepad application:

```
selectedmonitors:s:0,1
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:1
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1080
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,-3845,0,-1892,1036
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:pvsoa0068
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
drivestoredirect:s:
```

I'm afraid I'm going to get into trouble trying to do things I can’t handle. How can I restart my VDI ? Thanks for help.

Comment: VDI = Virtual Desktop Infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have turned the remote computer off.

Someone needs to restart it, so contact your administrator and ask
for it to be turned on.

If this is a virtual machine, the administrator may be able to restart it
remotely. If this is a physical machine, this might even require
a physical action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess once a colleague had the problem, but he had managed to restart the VDI. I don’t remember how he did....

Comment: In an enterprise environment, usually there is a server that can restart a stuck computer. Your network administrator will know how and can explain it, to be used the next time this happens. This is not an unusual happening, as computers can turn off for many causes, not only user errors. Windows Update is one cause, but there are many others.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).